# Unable to install/run SQL Server driver in WildFly 10

Tags: sql-server, server, wildfly, wildfly-10, mssql-jdbc

I am running my application on a WildFly 10 server. I do not wish to place my connection details on my application src codes thus am trying to place it inside WildFly 10 server itself.

However I am facing issues.

Under `[WILDFLY_HOME]\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft`, 
I created the following directory `sqlserver\main` and I place my JAR file and my XML file inside the main folder.

The JAR that I am using is `sqljdbc.jar`.

**module.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- JDBC Drivers module.xml file to configure your JDBC drivers-->

<!-- SQL Server 2014 example -->
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="sqljdbc.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Next under `[WILDFLY_HOME]\standalone\configuration`, I modified the `standalone.xml`. Under the subsystem datasource section, I add the details for SQL Server.

**standalone.xml:**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
            <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/TestDS" pool-name="TestDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\test:1433;databaseName=test</connection-url>
            <driver>mssql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>sa</user-name>
                <password>Password123!</password>
            </security>
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
                <prefill>false</prefill>
                <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            </pool>
            <validation>
                <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
            </validation>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
            <driver name="mssql" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

The error that I am facing now is as per below when I start running my WildFly:

```
15:19:51,098 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("data-source" => "TestDS")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql",
        "jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
        "org.wildfly.data-source.TestDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
        "jboss.driver-demander.java:/TestDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]",
        "org.wildfly.data-source.TestDS is missing [jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql]"
    ]
}
15:19:51,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.jdbc-driver.mssql (missing) dependents: [service org.wildfly.data-source.TestDS, service jboss.driver-demander.java:/TestDS]
```

Comment: Do you have "Unable to find driver class name in ... jar " in log?

Comment: Apart from any other problem, the class name for XA seems to be different according to this source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/understanding-xa-transactions?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue with this.

Since I place the file under this directory: `[WILDFLY_HOME]\modules\system\layers\base\com\microsoft`

Then the correct module location should be as per follow for normal datasource:

```
<driver name="mssql" module="system.layers.base.com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

or

if you are using xa datasource:

```
<driver name="mssql" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

credits to @jklee

Answer (score 4):

The driver is wrong, use

```
 <driver name="mssql" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
 </driver>
```

or

```
<driver name="mssql" module="com.microsoft.sqlserver">
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
</driver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `sqlserver` as global module as shown below

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
            <global-modules>
                <module name="com.microsoft.sqlserver" slot="main"/>
                <module name="com.sql.mysql" slot="main"/>
            </global-modules>
.
.
</subsystem>
```